# Можно ли запрограммировать горячие клавиши, чтобы вне зависимости от приложения они могли изменять редактируемый текст?

Tags: windows, текст

Например, я хочу, чтобы с помощью клавиатуры я, выделив строку, мог мгновенно изменить ее с "Ghbdtn" на "Привет", в каком месте я бы ни писал ее: в MS Word, в блокноте, в браузере при написании ответа или вопроса на форуме - в любом приложении.

Какие средства я могу использовать для реализации данной процедуры?
Можете также предложить готовые средства, если таковые имеются. Если такую возможность предоставляет ОС (Win10), то как их использовать?

Мне бы хотелось самому задавать правила изменения текста при нажатии клавиш. Т.е. то, что выше, - это только пример.

Comment: Это типа Punto Switcher?

Comment: @MAX, да, для данного примера - типа него. Но мне бы хотелось самому задавать правила изменения текста при нажатии клавиш.

Comment: Всё зависит от конкретных задач. Например в пунто я использую сокращения «_здр», которое меняется на «Здравствуйте, ». Если такого плана замены, то пунто вполне достаточно.

Comment: Думаю, всё это придётся делать на [WinAPI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/apiindex/windows-api-list). В частности, ставя [хуки](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/hook-reference), перехватывая ввод с [клавиатуры](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/keyboard-input) и [буфера обмена](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dataxchg/clipboard-functions).

Comment: А также функции из этого [списка](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/), такие как найти текущее окно, получить из него текст, задать текст.